# How to localize to specific targets in my Xcode project?

Tags: localization, internationalization, ios9, xcode8

I have multiple targets in my project, and only one target needs to be using localized strings. How do I make it so only that target will be localized (with .lproj) and the rest continues to use the development language? Currently Xcode allows you to add Localization to the entire project, not a specific target.

Comment: You can see optional solution at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692289/xcode-target-specific-localization?answertab=active#tab-top